# Parsing with sed issue

Tags: sed

I have a text file named `0test.txt` with the following snippet of code in it.  *(It has several http and https url links but these lines single it out)*

```
player.setup({
  file: 'http://website.com/site/myStream/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyXs',
  width: "100%",
  aspectratio: "16:9",

});
```

I can run a `sed` command:

```
cat /tmp/0test.txt | sed -n -e "/^ *file: */ { s/^ *file: *'//; s/', *$//p}"
```

And get back the correct URL link:

```
http://website.com/site/myStream/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyXs
```

But when the file `0test.txt` looks like this:

```
player.setup({
          file: 
'http://website.com/site/myStream/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9MTIvNC8yMDE5IDk6MTY6NTggUE0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT16RXpiUWowQ0V4TDJER3ExQnFZTEd3PT0mdmFsaWRtaW51dGVzPTM2MCZzdHJtX2xlbj0w',
          width: "100%",
          aspectratio: "16:9",
            aspectratio: "16:9"

    });
```

I do not get anything back. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the URL string really quoted with _single quotes_? AFAIK, that's not allowed in a JSON document. Also, that first JSON document ends with a dangling comma.  The general gist of a solution may be to remove the code bits with `sed` and then ask `jq` for the value associated with the `file` key, but since the JSON is malformed, that won't work.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using something along the line of `grep -E -o 'http.*[[:alnum:]]'` here?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes it's really quoted with single quotes.

Comment: @Fiximan I'm open to using grep or awk but the key is the text `file:`  There's dozen of other http and https urls but only one `file:`

Comment: Can you exclude that another URL (directly) follows a line with `file: <URL>`? If so you could use multiple instances of `grep`: `grep -A 1 'file:' <testfile> | grep -oE 'http.*' | sed "s:',$::"`

Comment: @Fiximan  yes that will work if you make that an answer I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific case, `grep` might be more useful. In a first step the buzzword `line:` is searched and and the following line added to the output. Then the URL itself is selected thereof using `grep` and finally `sed` for removing the trailing single quote and comma:

```
grep -A 1 'file:' <infile(s)> | grep -oE 'http.*' | sed "s:',$::"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your regular expression, you are allowing an arbitrary number of space-characters after the colon ("file: *"). You might want to expand that to a general whitespace character ("\s") so that line breaks and tabs are treated "like spaces".

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix.

```
cat /tmp/0test.txt|sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/file:\s*\n/file: /g;'
```

the line will transform the file in the way, that each line ending with "file:"  (with or without extra spaces at the end) will merge with a line going after it.

In this way, the text

```
player.setup({
          file: 
'http://website.com/site/myStream/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9MTIvNC8yMDE5IDk6MTY6NTggUE0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT16RXpiUWowQ0V4TDJER3ExQnFZTEd3PT0mdmFsaWRtaW51dGVzPTM2MCZzdHJtX2xlbj0w',
          width: "100%",
```

is going to transform to

```
player.setup({
          file: 'http://website.com/site/myStream/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9MTIvNC8yMDE5IDk6MTY6NTggUE0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT16RXpiUWowQ0V4TDJER3ExQnFZTEd3PT0mdmFsaWRtaW51dGVzPTM2MCZzdHJtX2xlbj0w',
          width: "100%",
```

and now you can use your old approach.